# Determine if an aspect ratio is closer to 16:9 or 4:3

Tags: geometry

I have a number of various different aspect ratios that I would like to categorize into two groups. One group that is closer to 4:3 aspect ratio and another group that is closer to 16:9.  Essentially, it's a matter of if ... then 16:9, else 4:3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question presumably has to do with where the "break point" should be.  My choice of break point would be the **geometric mean** of the two aspect ratios, where the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ is $\sqrt{ab}$. Thus the break point is at about $1.5396$ to $1$.  Another natural candidate is the arithmetic mean $(a+b)/2$, which here is about $1.5556$ to $1$.

Although the geometric mean seems to me, because of the multiplicative nature of aspect ratio, a better choice, in your problem, at the practical level, there is little difference between the two most reasonable options.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your given aspect ratios $u:v$ as $u/v$ to $16/9$ and $4/3$. Pick the closest.